# Bokeh HoverTool showing half the expected y-value

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

I'm getting this strange issue in Bokeh where tool tip is showing only half of the actual y-value. Has anyone had this issue before and resolved it?

[image]

Code looks like this:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models.ranges import FactorRange
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

output_notebook()

zip_counts = pd.DataFrame(df.zipcode.value_counts())

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
        ('Count', "@y")
    ])

p = Bar(zip_counts, title="abc", width=800, tools=[hover])
p.x_range = FactorRange(factors=zip_counts.index.tolist())

show(p)
```

Data Sample:

```
index   zipcode
10019   3414
10003   3196
10001   2719
10011   2561
10014   2523
10002   2486
10036   2451
10009   2282
10013   1822
10012   1641
10018   1575
```

I know those column headers are counterintuitive, try to look beyond it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I'm an idiot and didn't read far [enough in this post](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2965).
Needed to use @height, not @y.